# How can I find the amplitude of sine that produces a given arc curvature?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the amplitude ***a*** of a sine function `f[]` that results in a certain arc curvature. I know how to calculate the arc curvature by integrating over some range ***x***, se function `fCurvature[]` below, but I am having problems finding the amplitude ***a***. By manually trying out different values for ***a***, I have found that the value for ***a*** is approximately 0.207 at the target curvature *π/4*, but that is not the way to do it. The value for ***a*** should of course be computed. But how can I do that?

What I have is this:

```
f[a_ ,x_] = a Sin[x];
fCurvature[a_ ] = NIntegrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[f'[x]], x]], {x, 0, π}, WorkingPrecision -> 40];
(* Here I have tried NSolve[] and NDSolve[] but can not make it work. This is where your help is needed *)
```

Comment: "a" can be taken out of the integral because it is a constant. That gives "a Pi/2"

Comment: `f` has two arguments; consequently, `f'[x]` is meaningless. Functions that use numeric techniques should restrict their arguments to numeric values and use `SetDelayed`, e.g., `fCurvature[a_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: Curvature, or turned angle if you vant to call it that, is very much dependent of amplitude. If amplitude is very close to 0, then turned angle will be very close to 0 and the curve will look like a straight line. As amplitude increases, turned angle approaches the limit π. So I do not see how amplitude can be taken out of a computation of turned angle.  And it is not a linear funktion between amplitude and turned angle, so I think not "a π/2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, x_] = a*Sin[x];
```

Assuming that your definition is

```
fCurvature[a_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[D[f[a, x], x]], x]], {x, 0, π}];

sol = NSolve[fCurvature[a] == Pi/4, a][[1]]

(* NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{a -> 0.414214} *)

a /. sol // RootApproximant

(* -1 + Sqrt[2] *)
```

Comparing with exact

```
Assuming[a > 0,
 Integrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[D[f[a, x], x]], x]], {x, 0, π}]]

(* 2 ArcTan[a] *)

Solve[2  ArcTan[a] == Pi/4, a][[1]] // 
  FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* {a -> -1 + Sqrt[2]} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bob!